# Updating ImageView based on URL

Tags: android, android-imageview, picasso

I have spent a lot of time trolling through multiple different threads concerning this topic, but I have yet to find an answer that works well with my code (Android SDK 23, in 2016).  A lot of the answers are deprecated, and others just flat-out don't work like they're supposed to, and I was wondering if I could get a solid answer on this:

I am trying to include a Pokemon sprite (static image) in my program from Serebii. `nums` is a variable indicating the Pokemon's dex number (this one functions correctly, I promise). And this code is running in the main UI thread, which I know is frowned upon, but right now I'm trying to get the image loading, and then the smoothness of the app down.  **I don't really need a Bitmap, per se, but I need my `ImageView` to update and display the image given by the URL.  How do I do it?**

```
URL url = null;
try {
     url = new URL("http://www.serebii.net/xy/pokemon/" + nums + ".png");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
mImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: I think the best way to handle this is to perform an `AsyncTask` retrieving the Bitmap Image then after successfully retrieving it, just do what's in your code `mImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp)` provided that it is a bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library, it will do all your image loading. You only need to provide the url of the image correctly.

```
String url = "http://www.serebii.net/xy/pokemon/" + nums + ".png";

Picasso.with(yourContext)
    .load(url)
    .into(mImageView);
```

Comment: Your solution works! Thank you very much.  However, I have a question concerning why it alters my image's size from 100x100 to smaller.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Quontas Does your image view have `layout_width` and `layout_heigth` set to `wrap_content`?

Comment: Yes it does, but the image coming from Serebii and the image displayed in my application are two different sizes in themselves. And I need to correct myself, it's going from 120x120 to 100x100


Edit Edit:

Nevermind! It was exactly what you said! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Quontas I think you should consider adding `.resize(120, 120)`. Edit : allright, good luck! :)

Comment: @Quontas ..your problem has resolved , than you should have  accept these answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Picasso as:

```
Picasso.with(context)
          .load(url)
          .into(imageview);
```

Or use Universal Image loader as:

```
 ImageLoader imageLoader = new  ImageLoader(context);
 imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Piassco** library for it..[Library link](https://github.com/square/picasso)

For setting the `Bitmap` on the `ImageView`

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load("your url").into(new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            //do what ever you want with your bitmap 
          imgView.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);///imgView is use to set the image in it
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

        }
    });
```

And another method of **Picasso** :-

```
Picasso.with(this)
        .load("your_image_url")
        .placeholder(R.drawable.no_image)
        .error(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error)
        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)//user this for offline support
        .into(YOUR_IMAEGVIEW);
```

**OR**

You can also use the Universal Image Loader..Here is the link [Universal image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(); // Get singleton instance
            ImageLoader.getInstance().init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getActivity()));
            imageLoader = com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.getInstance();
              DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.YOUR_DRAWABLE)
                    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.YOUR_DRAWABLE)
                    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.YOUR_DRAWABLE)
                    .cacheInMemory(true)
                    .cacheOnDisk(true)
                    .considerExifParams(true)
                    .build();

imageLoader.displayImage("your_image_url", YOUR_IMAGEVIEW, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) Library to load images.
a) Add Gradle into your project.

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

b) Usage

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://www.serebii.net/xy/pokemon/" + nums + ".png").into(imageView);
```

Also there are another libraries, you can use like
[Fresco](http://frescolib.org/docs/index.html) by Facebook, [Universal Image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)